# Minimum and maximum values of expression

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

How to aproach the following problem:

> Find smallest and biggest values of the expression:
>   \begin{align*}
>   x^2+2y^2
> \end{align*}
>   When \begin{align*}
> x^2-xy+2y^2 &= 1 \end{align*}

Comment: lagrange optimization?

Comment: This problem was originally posted at math competition for 11 graders. I think that the solution of this problem does not require any derivatives or other fancy stuff.

Comment: Just to note, if $|x| \leq 1$ and $|y| \leq 1$, then it is easy to see that the max and min values of $x^2 + 2y^2$ are $1$ and $2$ respectively.

Comment: Nilabro, $(x-1/2y)^2+7/4y^2=1 >> \abs (y) \le \sqrt{4/7}$ Same can be done with $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x^2+2y^2=k$. Note that  from our conditions $k-1=x^2+2y^2-1=xy$. Because of $\text{AM-GM}$ we have that $$k=x^2+2y^2 \ge 2 \sqrt{2}xy =2\sqrt{2}(k-1)$$
Which gives us the maximum with equality when $x=\sqrt{2}y$.  Similarly, $$k=x^2+2y^2 \ge -2\sqrt{2}xy=-2\sqrt{2}(k-1)$$
Gives us the minimum with equality when $x=-\sqrt{2}y$. Thus we have $$\frac{8+2\sqrt{2}}{7} \ge x^2+2y^2 \ge \frac{8-2\sqrt{2}}{7}$$
We are done.